# sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode: not working right when changing font size

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextview, uifont, sizewithfont

I am having some problems with some UITextViews. You have the option to change the font size in my app, and when you change it, it reloads the content and resizes the textviews since there are multiple ones in the view. I am using the code below to do the resizing, but it will sometimes return the correct height, but as I change the text size in the app it seems to break down and return incorrect heights and the text in the textviews is getting cut off at the bottom. Can someone help me?

```
int height = [tempTextView.text sizeWithFont:
[UIFont fontWithName:fontFamily size:fontSizeF] 
constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 10000) lineBreakMode:
NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question & late answer, but it's still very relevant,

This sizeWithFont method is now deprecated, this new method works best

```
NSString *content = **Whatever your label's content is expected to be**
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(390, 1000);

NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] forKey: NSFontAttributeName];

CGSize newExpectedLabelSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:maximumLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:stringAttributes context:nil].size;
```

So you can adjust your label (or table cell etc) to

```
label.frame.size.height = newExpectedLabelSize.height;
```

I hope this helps, cheers, Jim.